# Is there a linear vector field satisfying these properties?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

I had a small question if this is possible while reading up a book.

I have a linear vector field $v(x) = Ax$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $x_0$ be a point such that $v(x_0) \not= 0$. Is there a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that, when restricted to a neighbourhood of $x_0$ sends $v$ to $(1, 0)$?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean ... that sends $v(x_0)$ (a vector) to $(1,0)$ (another vector)? A linear transform sending a function $v$ to a vector $(1,0)$ exists, but seems out of place for your context.

Comment: Actually, this was given by a friend. I'm guessing its $v(x)$.Only that seems to make sense. But since $v(x) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. I don't see how it is $(0,1)$?

Comment: It says "is sent to $(1,0)$". That is $Mv(x_0) = \pmatrix{1\\0}$ for some $M$.

Comment: But isn't $Mv(x_0) \in R^2$ as per the question?

Comment: I don't get it. $\pmatrix{1\\0}\in\mathbb R^2$, or what is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probably simplest transform sending $v(x_0) \ne 0$ to $(1,0)^T$ is given by
$$x \mapsto \frac1{\|v(x_0)\|_2^2}\pmatrix{v(x_0)_1 & v(x_0)_2 \\ 0& 0}x$$
Where $\|x\|_2 = \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2}$ is the euclidean norm of $x$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I fumbled there.What I meant was, how this solution related to the neighbourhood? I havn't seen you use that fact in your answer. What is $v(x_0)_1$ and  $v(x_0)_2$?

Comment: The neighborhood is all of $\mathbb R^2$ - there is no need to restrict, and $v(x_0)_i$ is the $i$-th component of the vector $v(x_0)$.

Comment: But this map isn't $(1,0)$ for all $x$ right? It says, restricted to a neighbourhood of $x_0$ should give me $(1,0)$. Not for the point $x_0$ alone. right?

Comment: No, no linear map can be any constant except for $(0,0)^T$.

Comment: Thank you.I talked to my friend about it.You're answer was more or less what he had in mind :)